# Package typewriter-effect changeDelay method doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In my React project I'm using `Typewriter` package.

It has method `changeDelay`, that doesn't actually work.

Here is an example number **1**:

```js
<Typewriter
  onInit={(typewriter) => {
    typewriter.typeString('Some text').changeDelay(1).start();
  }}
/>
```

In this case it should print text permanently, but it doesn't.

Here is example number **2**. It works fine, I can change delay.

```js
<Typewriter
  options={{
    strings: ['Some .'],
    delay: 80,
    autoStart: true,
    loop: true
  }}
/>
```

So, I have 2 questions.

1. For first example, is how I can actually change delay speed?

**OR**

2. For second example, is how I can prevent it from deleting text? (removing `autoStart` or/and `loop` doesn't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first the case, you can use prop `options` in order to change the delay:

```
import React from 'react';
import Typewriter from 'typewriter-effect';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Typewriter
      onInit={(typewriter) => {
        typewriter.typeString('Some text').changeDelay(1).start();
      }}
      options={{
        delay: 100,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 0):

Add one more Params options

```
<Typewriter 
   onInit={(typewriter) => {
   typewriter.typeString('Some text').changeDelay(1).start();
   }}
   options={{
      delay: 1, // set this according to your requirements
   }}
/>
```